# DataWeave Functions

Tags: mule, dataweave

This is my JSON request and I want to remove `dcsId` field from my JSON payload in DataWeave transformation.

How can I do that?

```json
{
    "status": "ok",
    "statusCode": "11011",
    "statusDescription": "Service: Get Profile ; Market: US ; Locale:en-US ; SourceId:DCS; ApiUid: 644e1dd7-2a7f-18fb-b8ed-ed78c3f92c2b; Description: The get profile call was successful.",
    "details": {
        "dcsId": "rfggrg",
        "marketCode": "US",
        "languageCode": "en",
        "profile": {
            "base": {
                "username": "abc",
                "firstName": "xc",
                "middleName": "test",
                "lastName": "123",
                "shortName": "xc",
                "displayName": "D",
                "suffix": "T",
                "prefix": "E"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To avoid mapping of other fields in payload, you can try this -

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
(payload - 'details') ++ (payload.details - 'dcsId')
```

It first gets everything in payload excepts details then add details by excluding dcsId.

HTH!

Comment: This expression, in addition to removing `dcsId` also removes the `details` field and promotes all fields of `details` one level up.  I am not sure this is what the OP described.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the the expression that just removes the dcsId

```
    (payload - 'details') ++ {details: payload.details - 'dcsId'}
```

Comment: In my opinion, this is the correct answer. The simpler you make your expression, the more bulletproof.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
    status : payload.status,
    statusCode : payload.status,
    statusDescription : payload.statusDescription,
    details :  payload.details - 'dcsId' 
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
(payload - 'details') 
++ 
details:(payload.details - 'dcsId')
```

Answer (score 0):

Script

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
    (payload - 'details') ++ {details: payload.details - 'dcsId'}
```

Output

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "statusCode": "11011",
  "statusDescription": "Service: Get Profile ; Market: US ; Locale:en-US ; SourceId:DCS; ApiUid: 644e1dd7-2a7f-18fb-b8ed-ed78c3f92c2b; Description: The get profile call was successful.",
  "details": {
    "marketCode": "US",
    "languageCode": "en",
    "profile": {
      "base": {
        "username": "abc",
        "firstName": "xc",
        "middleName": "test",
        "lastName": "123",
        "shortName": "xc",
        "displayName": "D",
        "suffix": "T",
        "prefix": "E"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive function to remove a key from any level of json payload

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var data = {
    "status": "ok",
    "statusCode": "11011",
    "statusDescription": "Service: Get Profile ; Market: US ; Locale:en-US ; SourceId:DCS; ApiUid: 644e1dd7-2a7f-18fb-b8ed-ed78c3f92c2b; Description: The get profile call was successful.",
    "details": {
        "dcsId": "rfggrg",
        "marketCode": "US",
        "languageCode": "en",
        "profile": {
            "base": {
                "username": "abc",
                "firstName": "xc",
                "middleName": "test",
                "lastName": "123",
                "shortName": "xc",
                "displayName": "D",
                "suffix": "T",
                "prefix": "E"
            }
        }
    }
}

fun removeKey(val, keyToRemove) = val match {
    case is Array -> $ map ((v) -> removeKey(v, keyToRemove))
    case is Object -> ($ - keyToRemove) mapObject ((value, key, index) -> {(key): removeKey(value,keyToRemove)})
    else -> $
  }
---
removeKey(data,"dcsId")
```